# run an OpenShift gear on-demand

Tags: apache-camel, openshift, redhat

I have a gear with JBoss Fuse and Apache Camel consuming a considerable amount of memory that needs to run a nightly task, i.e. it needs to be activated only at a specific time of the day, run its routes, and then shutdown.

Is there a way to accomplish this on OpenShift?

Comment: Why not use a camel quartz component to schedule the route?

Comment: It's already the case, but I don't want the gear to be active when the route is not running.

Comment: Aaah I see. Valid point.

Comment: Can you use the REST API to start/stop the application with calls managed by `cron`?

Answer (score 0):

```
rhc cartridge add cron
```

In the `.openshift/cron/` directory you can place your cron job, make it executable, add with git, commit and push it